# How consider home folder as root folder?

Tags: debian, chroot, sftp

I create users who each have their own home directory, normal.

Currently I create my user as follows:

```
adduser -d / home / ftp / myUser myUser
```

My users need to connect to SFTP (open ssh installed on my vps), and I need that when my users connect in SFTP, I need the home directory to be considered as his root folder

Why ? another application is connecting to this SFTP, and if it is not considered in its root directory, the application can not send or read the files.

How can I do that?

Comment: "_I need to create users who will only be able to access their directory, the user should not see the other directories._". Since you write that you are  "_new to the administration of a Linux server_" I need to ask if you **really** need to do this, or is it acceptable simply to say that users must not be able to see into each others' directories?

Comment: @roaima Yes i really need. An other software connec via sftp and if it is not root folder of user, it does not works

Comment: @roaima I think yes

Comment: @roaima it's done

Comment: See `ChrootDirectory` in the `sshd_config` manual.

Comment: @Kusalananda I try with Match User myUser
        ChrootDirectory /home/ftp/myUser
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
But after restart ssh, I can not connect to sftp : Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Comment: There are many tutorials on the web about how to set up SFTP in a chrooted environment.   Update your question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add or change `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to include the following lines

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftpusers
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

And then add all the set of your constrained users to the `sftpusers` group.

Finally, change ownership of the target directories to be root, and remove group/other write permission, and restart the `ssh` server. This is necessary for the chroot to become effective. The downside is that the user will not be able to write any files into their home directory. (You will have to create subdirectories for them to write into.)

It's not an ideal situation from a user's perspective and you may find it better to create a directory elsewhere in the filesystem for SFTP to use (eg `/home/sftp/$USER`) that can be locked down independently from their real home directory using `ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u`).

When you have problems (and you probably will the first during few attempts to get this right), remember to read `/var/log/auth.log` to see what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks !!  I forgot to change ownership to root !! It works